# Algorithm for multiplication without "*" operator? In pseudocode?

Tags: pseudocode

I'm a beginner to programming (learning python right now). Ran across this question, and am completely lost as to how to get the algorithm and how to write it in pseudocode.

I'm sorry for asking. I'd really like some help though and would appreciate any help at all.

Comment: Is this a homework question? Multiplication is nothing but repeated addition.

Comment: I suggest `if(x is 0 or y is 0) {return 0} else {return x ÷ (1 ÷ y)}`. Works for non-integers too.

Answer (score 0):

For positive integers multiplication can be replaced by addition. For example: `3 x 4 = 3 + 3 + 3 + 3`

You can then replace multiple additions with a loop, for example

```
int result = 0
int a = 3
int b = 4

// calculate a x b
for 1 .. b
        result = result + a
end for
```

So the loop works like this

```
result = 0 + 3
result = 3 + 3
result = 6 + 3
result = 9 + 3

print result   // 12
```

Comment: *"Multiplication can be replaced by addition"* - for non-negative integers only, though.